# Windows 10 SSD speeds are slow

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, macbook

I have a mid-2012 MacbookPro that I replaced the internal HDD with an Team GX2 512GB SSD. I tinkered around with the boot system to where now I have installed MacOS, Manjaro Linux, and Windows 10 on the drive. My problem is that in Windows (no problem anywhere else) the SSD is constantly at 100% even though the read and write speeds are below 1MB/s most of the time. I know from Manjaro that this SSD works fine at 200-300MB/s. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more system info. or want me to find anything else out to help you help me than I would be glad to do so, if you need screen shots ask, but I didn't because Windows is seriously really slow and I didn't have the patience to do that.
Thanks,

--rosterkid05

Comment: What process/service is causing the usage percent _(Task Manager Process tab, sort by Disk)_? _(General FYI, Macs are notorious for low CPU/RAM specs, which will cause issues on Windows because it's resource-heavy)_

Comment: maybe a wrongly installed or missing driver
look in the device manager, right click on the start menu>run>devmgmt.msc and check that there is no yellow triangle somewhere.

Comment: I'd reinstall the Boot Camp drivers. Far to much to précis in an answer, but see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923

Comment: @JW0914 All of the other processes are below 50%, so it is not a cpu or ram bottleneck. I would think that maybe a program or service is hogging resources, but it shows it only topping out at 1-5MB/s which is way to slow for my SSD, as shown in Manjaro and MacOS.

Comment: I will look into the driver reinstall a little later in the day

Comment: Update, it know goes into startup repair every time on boot and if i try to boot into recovery mode it fails and just reboots back to recovery menu. It also will not let me reinstall windows. Manjaro and MacOS still works fine and as intended. any help is greatly appreciated.